# How to properly place an object based on axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to place a rectangle in one of my graphs. However it seams that I am mixing dimensions. Is there a way to make sure that `\draw` uses the same dimension and would fill what is currently enclosed by "estimates"?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            width=0.8\textwidth,
            height=0.4\textwidth,
    ]
    \addplot {-x};
        \addlegendentry{model}
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1,1)
        (1,2)
        (2,2)
        (2,1)
        (1,1)
    };
        \addlegendentry{estimate}
\end{axis}  

    \draw[fill=blue] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have also tried moving the $\draw$ inside the $axis$ environment but that's not the solution either.

Comment: Here is a help how you can [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863). `$...$` should be used only for math mode code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the `\draw` inside the `axis` and use the `axis cs` coordinate system, as in `\draw[fill=blue] (axis cs:1,1) rectangle (axis cs:2,2);`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            width=0.8\textwidth,
            height=0.4\textwidth,
    ]
    \addplot {-x};
        \addlegendentry{model}
    \addplot coordinates {
        (1,1)
        (1,2)
        (2,2)
        (2,1)
        (1,1)
    };
        \addlegendentry{estimate}
    \draw[fill=blue] (axis cs:1,1) rectangle (axis cs:2,2);
\end{axis}  


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```